# Spring MVC and Angularjs

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, angularjs

Currently I´m trying to learn `Angular JS`, but firstly I want to setup my environment with `Spring mvc`.

At the moment I only want to work with rest, but I have a doubt for what is the best way to place the resoucres in `Spring MVC`

My simple applicaction has this squeleton:

```
my-simple-app:
 src
   main
     java
     resources
   webapp
     resources
     WEB-INF
```

If I want to put the `app` folder from the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), what is the best place to put it?

I tried to put in `src/webapp/resources/app` but then I have to move the `html` files to WEB-INF?

How was your skeleton in your angular-js spring mvc applications?

What is the best way to do the redirect to the `app/index.html`? to the welcome file and then work only with `angularjs` `$routeproviders`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can understand, your Front End technology is *Angualar JS* and your Back End technology is *Spring MVC*.

I'm a Front End developer and hence I can provide you the advice on the structure of your HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Here are my recommendations:

1. Mode Of Communication Between Front End and Back End: JSON (Should be strictly followed for MVC Pattern)
2. File Location: All your Front End files should be in WEB-INF folder with this structure:

   - `WEB-INF/Assets`: All your JavaScript Files, JavaScript Libraries, Images, CSS etc. Should Be Places Here. You Can Open A Separate Folder Each Resource Type Inside Assets
   - `WEB-INF/JSP`: All Your JSPs should be placed here. As Angular's greatest strength is Single page Application, you can create one JSP per main page and place them here
   - `WEB-INF/HTML`: All the static resources that would be injected into the JSPs using `<ng-view>`or `<ng-include>` can be placed here

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to get going is to take all the files in the `angular-seed/app` directory and copy them into your `src/main/webapp` directory.  After copying these files, you should be able to redeploy the app and have a running sample.

Most servlet containers will include index.html as a default welcome file.  If yours doesn't, you can add that config in web.xml `<welcome-file-list>`.

The WEB-INF directory is for web resources that should not be exposed directly to the web.  web.xml is a example of a file that should not be exposed to remote users.  In this case, it's safe to expose all of the app's resources directly to the web; thus you don't need to place the resources under WEB-INF.

Comment: note though, if he uses spring MVC, and he has the spring-mvc dispatcher servlet mapped to /, this will hijack all requests :)

Comment: Also for a secure app dont want to expose all js and html which have business validations and front end flows and algorithms to the world. If under web-inf then only logged in / users with appropriate roles will be served those files

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this structure for your project:

```
my-simple-app:
    src
        main
            java
                controller
                    MySpringCtr.java
                models
                    Person.java
                    House.java
                    *.java
        webapp
            WEB-INF
                resources
                    css
                        style.css
                        *.css
                    js
                        angularCtr.js
                        *.js
                pages
                    index.jsp
                    *.jsp
                mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
                web.xml
```

I found a tutorial for beginners which explains step by step how to combine SpringMVC and AngularJS, you can find the tutorial and the complete code [in this blog](http://www.luigisworld.com/2013/12/combining-springmvc-with-angularjs.html) I hope it will be useful :)