# Angular js with spring mvc

Tags: angularjs

Currently trying to implement angular js with spring mvc

Tried to implement the sample project **springmvc-angularjs-master** from the site-https://github.com/xvitcoder/spring-mvc-angularjs , not sure how to use the folder structure of this sample project into a spring project.

i read the thread - [Spring MVC and Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617381/spring-mvc-and-angularjs)
but still could not find the solution. Do i need to create new folder webapp under the src folder in the web application?

can someone help me how to convert this sample project into spring web application?
i am not using maven and using simple web application with spring capabilites in  myeclipse ide.

Current project folder structure:

SampleApp

-src

```
  --controller,bean folders
```

-webroot

```
 --webinf
     ---web.xml,springmvc.xml
     ---html folder(index.html,etc.,)
 --resources
     ---js
         ----app.js,services.js,controller.js and lib folder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to import the project as Maven project (Import > Maven > Existing MavenProject) and run it as is. All of the necessary mappings can be found in /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webapp-config.xml

Once you have your head wrapped around that, you should be able to extract what you need.

I also noticed some of the @override annotations were throwing some errors. I just removed them.

Comment: Thanks.followed the steps as mentioned but could not figure out the problem. so tried out a new approach -backend using spring mvc restful with jackson and front end with angular js seed project. created the restful application using the link - "http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/" and it works by hitting the url as mentioned in demo, but on integrating with angular js it did not work. i dont know how to continue as i messed up the code. can you please give some links using angular js with spring mvc?

Comment: Sure. Give me a couple hours.

Comment: Are you using Spring Tool Suite?

Comment: i tried calling the request mapping from services.js of angular class... request itself not processing.. actually i need to create something like this as in the  link "https://github.com/teunh/jfall2012", but request itself not going..

Comment: Try to get this example running: http://codetutr.com/2013/04/09/spring-mvc-easy-rest-based-json-services-with-responsebody/

Comment: once you get that working, integrating AngularJS should be easy.

Comment: integrated with angular js and on hitting the url -http://locahost:9080/SampleApplication/index.html - it throws error-404:Not found.  how to hit the application with angular js and spring rest?

Comment: Try this... Pull down a fresh copy of the sample project from the repo (https://github.com/xvitcoder/spring-mvc-angularjs). Open a terminal and `cd` into the project directory. Then execute `mvn tomcat:run`.

Comment: My previous comment assumes you have Maven installed.

Comment: for this poc work i am not using maven,but still i will try doing it

Comment: hi moderndegree, can you please help me with the query regarding angularjs $resource- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424744/passing-param-object-from-resource-get-method-to-restful-services