# Passing param object from $resource get method to restful services

Tags: angularjs-resource

i have query regarding passing param objects to $resource get method.

in the backend restful application i am not getting the routeparam values passed .
here my sample code

on clicking the search button from the html page it is moving to  controller as mentioned in myapp.js

myapp.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'MyServices']);

app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

```
$routeProvider  
.when('/employeesearch/:empID/:deptID', {
    templateUrl : 'partials/result.html',
    controller : SearchController
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/defaultsearch'
});} ]);
```

on doing console.log in controller.js file , the routeparams values are displayed correctly

SearchController.js

function SearchController($scope, $routeParams, EmployeeSearch) 
$scope.mydata = EmployeeSearch.getSearchResult($routeParams.empID,$routeParams.deptID);

}

myservices.js

angular.module('MyServices', ['ngResource']).

```
factory('EmployeeSearch', function($resource){
return $resource('rest/employees/:eID/:dID', {}, {
query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:false},
getSearchResult:{method:'GET', params:{eID:'empID',dID:'deptID'}}
});
});
```

backend restful java class

@Path("/employees")
public class EmployeeSearchService {

@Path("{eID}/{dID}")

@GET

@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public Employee searchmethod(@PathParam("eID") String empId, @PathParam("dID") String deptId) {

```
     System.out.println("eid:"+empId);
     System.out.println("did:"+deptId);
        return new Employee(); }
```

on hitting the restful url :http:localhost:9080/MyProject/rest/employees/e12/d12
 - the value of eid is 'e12' and did is "d12"

but on hitting via the anugular 
it is displaying the value of eid as "empID" and did as "deptID",

it is displaying the value as i mentioned in the myservices.js file

Can you please help me out in this? what am i giving wrongly?

Reference site: https://github.com/teunh/jfall2012/blob/master/demo/web/index.html

Comment: You are passing the string value 'empID' and 'deptID' at this line `getSearchResult:{method:'GET', params:{eID:'empID',dID:'deptID'}}`.

Comment: but the empID and deptID are the routeparams name in the app.js, so i thought it should take the values from the url. sorry i just started learning angular js. then how should i pass the value to restful services?

Comment: the params is for default values, you can pass the values in your call to getSearchResult instead as `EmployeeSearch.getSearchResult({eID: $routeParams.empID, dID: $routeParams.deptID});`

Comment: @Benny, you should post your comment as an answer and pick up the points. I'm pretty sure that is what he was after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is for default values thus they are sent to the server when you didn't provide them in your call to `getSearchResult` (`empID` and `deptID`)

```
factory('EmployeeSearch', function($resource){
    return $resource('rest/employees/:eID/:dID', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:false},
        getSearchResult:{method:'GET', params:{eID:'empID',dID:'deptID'}}
    });
});
```

To pass the values you captured in `$routeParams`, you can pass the values in an object in the call to `getSearchResult` in your controller as follow:

```
function SearchController($scope, $routeParams, EmployeeSearch) {
    $scope.mydata = EmployeeSearch.getSearchResult({
        eID: $routeParams.empID,
        dID: $routeParams.deptID
    });
}
```

Note that the key of the object has to match the name of your resource path parameter (`:eID` and `:dID`)

Comment: now i understood the meaning of the params. it is working.Sorry i dont know how to give points and i accepted your answer.thanks this is the exact answer i was looking for.